# In Serializer field validation ,serializer validate function is not working

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

[code image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTOWk.png)

output:
serializer.save()
File "C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 204, in save
validated_data = {**self.validated_data, **kwargs}
TypeError: 'ValidationError' object is not a mapping

Comment: your validate method will fail when you provide some values for both first name and last name. Also please don't use images for your code .https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Your validation statement

```py
if data['firstName'] and data['lastName']:
```

is causing the error. Though the intention isn't clear on why you're doing this, I assume that you're sending both firstName and lastName in the POST request body. Either modify the validation statement or don't send both firstName and lastName in your request. This should solve you're issue.

Comment: def validate(self,data):

        if data['firstName'] == data['lastName']:
            return serializers.ValidationError('first name last name cannot be same')
        return data
    
    I have changed the condition,but still getting the same error

Comment: same post with code:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76712594/validate-function-is-not-working-in-object-level-validation