# validate function is not working in object level validation

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-forms

`views.py`:

```py
from rest_framework import generics
from .models import Identity
from .serializers import IdentitySerializer
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view

@api_view(['GET'])
def IdentityListApiView(request):
   queryset = Identity.objects.all()
   serializer = IdentitySerializer(queryset, many=True)
   return Response(serializer.data)

@api_view(['POST']) 
def IdentityDetailApiView(request):
    serializer = IdentitySerializer(data=request.data)
    print("isData valid:", serializer.is_valid())
    if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
         serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
```

`serializers.py`

```py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Identity

class IdentitySerializer(serializers.Serializer):
    firstName=serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    lastName=serializers.CharField(max_length=40)
    age=serializers.IntegerField(max_value=None, min_value=None)
    mobileNo=serializers.IntegerField(read_only=False)
    isMale=serializers.BooleanField(read_only=False)

    def create(self, validated_data):  
      return Identity.objects.create(**validated_data)

    def validate(self, data):
        if data['firstName'] == data['lastName']:
            return serializers.ValidationError('first name last name cannot be same')
        return data
```

`models.py`

```py
from django.db import models

class Identity(models.Model):
    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, default='M')
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=False, blank=False, default='K')
    age = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    mobileNo = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    isMale = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
```

When I make a POST request to `http://127.0.0.1:8500/application/identity/` with
following request body:

```json
{
    "firstName": "abc",
    "lastName": "abc",
    "age": "56",
    "mobileNo":" 589643145",
    "isMale": true
}
```

Instead of raising a `ValidationError` with the validation **"first name last name cannot be same"** as output, it fails with the following message:

```
"C:\Python310\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 204, in save
    validated_data = {**self.validated_data, **kwargs}
TypeError: 'ValidationError' object is not a mapping"
```

Comment: you should raise errors instead of returning it.  `raise serializers.ValidationError('first name last name cannot be same')`

Comment: remove the create method, this function does not make sense and it comes before validate function